# Will WordPress Auto Update work on a site with Basic Authentication enabled?

Tags: automatic-updates

I'm trying to setup WordPress Auto Patching on a site with Basic Authentication enabled (ie via .htaccess).

I've setup a proper cron job to trigger the Auto Update process (with the Basic Authentication credentials in the URL so as to avoid this being blocked), however the Auto Update still doesn't seem to work.

Is the presence of Basic Authentication likely to be the problem here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will work. For Updates, WP reaches out to the update servers, there is no incoming request that is necessary. Your WP doesn't even have to be publicly reachable at all, you can have it behind a NAT router and (auto-) updates will still work just fine.

Comment: the problem is not the update but the cron jobs. WordPress call itself to launch cron jobs in background then the Basic Authentication blocks this. try this workaround : http://nickohrn.com/2014/07/quick-tip-wp-cron-http-basic-protected-site/

Comment: Thanks both for your help.  I've setup a proper cron job via cPanel so these issues should now resolve themselves.